# Handle server response errors

Tags: angular, nginx, cors, ionic3

I am having a problem and I have looked for a solution but I cannot find it.

I have an Ionic v3 app and I am consuming an external service (nginx). When I make the requests and the server responds with a 200, everything works fine. But when I get an error, for example 404 or others, I get the following message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url_server.com' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Checking the server side settings are like this:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,TRACE,PATCH,OPTIONS,CONNECT;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization;
```

The strange thing is that, as I mentioned, when the login request or any other service is correct, I have no problem consuming the service, but when it fails due to a controlled error, I receive the commented error, without being able to capture it.

This way I am trying to call the service:

```
async testCallService(domain, data) {
    const res = await this.http
      .post(this.config.getURLfor(domain, 'url_server', {}), data)
      .toPromise();
    return res;
}
```

function call;

```
await this.ws.testCallService(this.session.session_user.domain, checklist).then(
      async (data: any) => {
        load.dismiss();
        const alert = await this.alert.create({
          cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
          header: 'Title',
          message: 'Message ' + data.grade + '%',
          buttons: ['OK'],
        });
        await alert.present();
      },
      (error) => {
        load.dismiss();
        this.app.crearToast(error.error.message, 'danger');
      }
);
```